# Remove everything between tag Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I m trying to remove everything inside any html tag:

input:

```
<a class="yoyo"> <h1 id="test"> hello </h1> </a>
```

weird example but well

output:

```
<a><h1>hello</h1></a>
```

I ve tried `/(<\w)(?:.*)(>)/gmi` but its not working...

If you have any clue on that .
Thanks

---

So to explain it more after your comment I scrapped a website and I have a .txt file that i wanna clean. It will contain the whole html of a page and i want to clean every single html tag and remove the spaces aswell.
So everything between any <* and > should be removed.

Comment: Can you elaborate? you can have a million html tags inside html tags, what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: does the regex have to change "hello" into "salut" and remove spaces too? Just kidding for the hello, but i am serious for the spaces..

Comment: Don't do this with regex.

Comment: Why don't you use JS utilities (which are built particularly well for parsing and manipulating markup) rather than use regular expression ([terrible choice for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1612146))

Comment: Obligatory link to "that post" <snip> George!!!  *shakes fist*

Comment: are you working with a string or actual html? If the second, it would be a better approach to just remove the attributes with `element.removeAttribute(attrName);`

Comment: **Don't Parse HTML With Regex**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this using DOM methods. Loop over all elements, iterate the attributes and remove them

```js
let cont = document.getElementById('demo-container'),
  els = cont.querySelectorAll('*');

[].slice.call(els).forEach(el => {
  [].slice.call(el.attributes).forEach(attr => {
    el.removeAttribute(attr.name);
  })
});

console.log(cont.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="demo-container">
  <a class="yoyo">
    <h1 id="test"> hello </h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following regex:

```
<[^>]*>
```

You will have to concatenate all the matches.

Comment: Tell me if i m wrong but it seems that your regex remove every thing between the tag. Like for example <a ***> hello <a> becomes <a ***><a> or  i want to remove everything inside the tags so <a ***> hello<a> becomes <a><a>

Comment: I get it. How about this: (<\/?\w+)[^>]*(>) You will have to concatenate the match groups in this one.